# How can I change the fill color in boxplot

Tags: r, colors, boxplot

I want to change the fill color in boxplot with the follwing code, but the code color only change the color of the border.

```
p = ggplot(data=concentration,aes(factor(status), con), ylim=c(0,0.15),cex.axis=1.5,cex.lab=15) + 
stat_summary(fun.data=f, geom="boxplot", position="dodge",color='blue') + 
ylab(expression(paste("Formaldehyde concentration"," (",mu,"g/",m^3,")"))) +
xlab("") + 
ylim(0,200) #+ 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Condition))
```

How can I change the fill color?

Comment: plase add the chart you get and a small output of the data you use is always helpfull

Comment: try `fill = "blue"` instead of `color = "blue"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the ways to edit the aesthetics of a ggplot boxplot here: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html

- alpha
- colour
- fill
- group
- linetype
- shape
- size
- weight

In your case you want to change the fill:

```
set.seed(123)
concentration <- data.frame(status = c("Yes", "No"), con = rnorm(n = 30) + 10)

ggplot(data=concentration, aes(factor(status), con)) + 
geom_boxplot(fill = "blue")
```

[image]